# rpy2 import works in shell but not in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, rpy2

So, I have installed rpy2 successfully, and I can import it in a python shell, for example.  Also, I have Jupyter notebook successfully installed.  But for some reason I cannot import rpy2 on the jupyter notebook.  I get the standard 'module not found' error.  Other posts have addressed problems relating to installation of rpy2 itself, but specifically, I can't import ONLY from jupyter notebook. I find it quite strange, because I'm fairly certain I only have one copy of Python 3.6, so why can it import in the terminal but not in the notebook.  .. .

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by re-installing jupyter notebook. . .

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and I use many different env with conda. Here is my solution, starting your jupyter notebook with the same env which rpy2 is installed.